# Find matrices which are fixed by a certain permutation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

> Let $H$ be an adjacency matrix of a graph. Given a certain permutation matrix $P$ such that $PHP^T=H$, describe the structure of the graph corresponding to $H$ (or the matrix).

This problem is opposite of computing automorphism group of a graph. If $\sigma$ is a permutation associated with the matrix $P$, then we have $H_{\sigma(i), \sigma(j)}=H_{i,j}$. I don't think I can say anything more about the graph. Can you point me towards references where such problem is studied in detail?

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is consider the action of the permutation $P$ on the edges of the complete graph $K_{n}$. These edges will be partitioned into orbits. Then the edges of the graph with adjacency matrix $H$ must be made up of a union of these edge orbits.